# How to mount iso9660 filesystem as read write

Tags: boot, mount, iso, data-cd

Hey my iso file won't accept device files so I was wondering how I could mount a cdrw with an iso9660 filesystem as read write to copy device files to the cdrw.

Comment: Mounting it read-write (if that was possible, which I don't believe it is) won't allow you to create device files either. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: afaik isofs does not implement write() so you can never effectivly write into the iso. you need some tools to edit iso files. this would be a nice use case for fuse, but afaik such an implementation does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mount iso9660 read-write, the filesystem is laid out for reading only (there is no space for files to grow, for example). I don't know if you can create such a filesystem with device nodes either. What are you trying to do?  If you want to create a custom LiveCD, look at the tools your favorite distribution uses to do that.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom linux distro but the kernel won't mount the root filesystem.

Comment: I think maybe you can use another filesystem, on a USB stick.